# Wordpress: PHP script cannot be find HTTP 404 ERROR

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, action

My current mission is to create a complete theme on WordPress. And to this is, a login system. Now, i've created the form and everything looks just fine, the problem is that wordpress is brawling with me and cannot locate my signup script, it creates a HTTP 404 error. Now I think that this has something to do with wordpress permalink system because it wants to find a page, instead of my `signup.inc.php` script.

Now this frustrates me because im kind of new to coding and I have no idea how to fix it!

Here is my code linking to the actual file located in a folder called 'includes'

```
  <form action='includes/signup.inc.php' method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="uid" id="uid" placeholder="Username" required>
        <small id="userhelp" class="form-text text-muted">This name will show on forums and the socialpage.</small>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstn" placeholder="Firstname" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" id="lastn" placeholder="Lastname" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email Adress</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="mail" id="inputemail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email" required>
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="password">Repeat password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd-repeat" id="password" placeholder=" Repeat password" required>
        <small id="passHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please retype your password.</small>
      </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="invalidCheck3" required>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck3">Agree to terms and conditions</label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        You must agree before submitting.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
      <button class="btn btn-dark" name="signup-submit" type="submit">Signup</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: This should rather not be handled “outside” of WordPress to begin with, but get implemented as a proper plugin or something …

Comment: _“Now I think that this has something to do with wordpress permalink system”_ - it doesn’t (unless you messed with what WP does in terms of routing by default somehow) - all requests for physically existing files or folders are left alone by it.

Comment: Is the `action='includes/signup.inc.php'` looking it the right place? shouldn't it be relative? like : `action='<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/includes/signup.inc.php'` or something like that. Or even just adding the `/`  infront of `includes`

Answer (score 0):

Please use this action in form:

```
<form action='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/includes/signup.inc.php' method="post">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I already have a header and a footer implemented on the page and as a separate page i us `page-login-page.php` I've really tried everything to reach the file. And I really don't know where it's pointing at because it's a 404 message which means it's not found! Maybe im missing code of some sort?

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer please check `get_template_directory_uri()` this function will give you to the path of theme-folder so path will you get from this function is ->  `http://localhost/wordpressfolder/wp-content/themes/themename/`

so finally our path become `http://localhost/wordpressfolder/wp-content/themes/themename/includes/signup.inc.php`  please set path according your needs but do not add static please set it by function which i mentioned